# How to run a program remotely and show it locally?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-access

I have Windows 7 Ultimate on two PCs. I would like to open a program (like Firefox) on one PC, but have its window displayed on the other. Is this possible with Windows? Any programs I need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both PCs are in a same network, try **Remote Desktop** to see another PC window and even control it.

Or if your PCs aren't in same network, For example PC1 in NewYork and another one in China. You need **Valid IP** but it costs and maybe complex for you instead of it try softwares Like **Team Viewer**.

Comment: or RealVNC if you don't like "Remote Desktop"

Comment: Yes, Exactly...

Comment: @cybernard: Remote Desktop nowadays allows sharing of a single application window, VNC doesn't (it has extensions a la UltraVNC's "share this rectangle on the screen", but the behavior thereof is not quite optimal.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).  PSExec is an unofficial Microsoft program from the Winternals group.

Comment: Why "unofficial"? There's even an official book about the Sysinternals tools (Windows Sysinternals Administrator's Reference)!

Comment: the winternals tools are not officially supported.  But they work!

Comment: Just bear in mind that PSExec is a command line tool in the same vein as SSH for *nix. The OP was asking about graphical applications (eg. Firefox) which PSExec does not cater for (to my knowledge!)

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop or VNC are what you need.
For Remote Desktop, there is a simple [walk through](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista) on how to enable it on Windows.

If your computers are 'far' away from each other that you need to reach the other computer over the Internet, things might be more tricky. You might need to do port forwarding, configure firewalls, etc. A simpler solution for this situation will be [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).

Answer (score 0):

Remote desktop software will allow you to remotely control another computer, and see a limited amount of what is going on, on that remote computer.  Some programs will be displayed, some will not.  Also, there may be color display issues.  For example, to speed up the rate at which you are getting new information, many people use their RDP/VNC connection at 256 colors.

What you might be thinking of, is actually using a second computer as another monitor... which is different.  Software like [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) allows you to use any computer with a network connection to be used as an actual second monitor.  You would control what you see on that second computer as if it was simply a monitor attached to the main computer... and you would do it *from* the main computer.  This sounds like what you are actually asking about.